# AngularJS with Modernizr not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modernizr

I'm using AngularJS and Modernizr in order to detect media queries and call a function on every window / viewport resize. What I'm trying to do is set an element display depending on the desktop or mobile query - some elements ought to display on mobile only, others on desktop only.

A browser does detect element show / hide functionality on initial load, however I can't make it work on browser resize.

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, Modernizr) {
    $scope.desktopOrMobile = function () {
        // mobile logic
        if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)')) {
            // show only for mobile, hide desktop
            $scope.showD = false;
            $scope.showM = true;    
        };
        // desktop logic
        if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 992px)'))  {
            // show only for desktop, hide mobile
            $scope.showD = true;
            $scope.showM = false;
        };
    };
    $scope.desktopOrMobile();
}
```

Directive for resizing:

```
myApp.directive('resizeAction', ['$window', 'Modernizr', function($window, Modernizr) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // A = Attribute
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            angular.element($window)
            .bind('resize', function () {
                $scope.desktopOrMobile();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

To show you what I mean in details, here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/knele90/Lvc0u55v/12475/

Any help would be appreciated, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to had the event to the $window object

in your link function in 'resizeAction' directive you can try this :

```
$window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        $scope.desktopOrMobile();
 });

// Don't forget to destroy it
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $window.removeEventListener('resize');
});
```